# Let $D$ be an effective divisor on a regular surface $X$. What is $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_D$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be an effective divisor on a regular surface $X$. Is it easy to describe $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_D$?

The case I'm most interested in is when $X$ is an integral scheme projective and flat over a Dedekind scheme $S$, and $D$ is an effective vertical divisor. Then I believe the degree of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_D$ should be either zero if $D = X_s$ for some $s\in S$, or negative if it is a proper subset of some $X_s$ - is there a way to view this without intersection theory?

Comment: If $D$ is regular too, then  the sheaf  $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_D$ is the normal line bundle  to $D$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Why does $D$ being regular here matter? Can't you just take the canonical exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X|_D\rightarrow 0$ and tensor with $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)$ to get that $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)|_D$ is the conormal sheaf of $D$, so $\mathcal{O}_X(D)|_D$ is the normal sheaf? What goes wrong here?

Comment: I just meant that if $D$ is regular we have a geometric  interpretation of the normal line bundle  just like in differential geometry (or complex manifold theory),  while in the general case the conormal sheaf is not locally free and neither is its dual, so that the situation is less clear geometrically, even though  the algebro-geometric definition is perfectly rigorous.